# I have Chinese text in an image, I'm looking for a translation please

Tags: learning

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what the writing on the sticker means. What type of wood is this? And Name? Thank you!

Comment: I'm also finding mixed answers online for the meaning of Hua Yi.

Answer (score 2):

华艺：brand name, not a word

- 华：China or Flower
- 艺：Art

编号：number

品名：name

- 品：item
- 名: name

药柜：medicine closet (but probably means just a drawer of it here)

- 药：medicine
- 柜：closet

木质：wood

- 木：wood
- 质：matrial

榆木：elm / Ulmus pumila L

规格：spec, here means size
84 * 45 * 116 (mm)

Comment: Thank you so much! It's greatly appreciated!